# Getting SQL to return data ONLY for the last business day

Tags: sql

I have tried about a thousand different ways to attempt this after hours of scouring the internet and finding things that seem like they would work, I still have not been able to get this to come up correctly.

I have a query that I am running in SQL via Tableau that I need to be dynamic and change to look at ONLY business days.  When I updated my query this morning, since our server looks at one day prior, it was looking for Sunday data which in my company there is no processing going on on Saturday or Sunday, I need it to know when today is Monday, (basically) do getdate()-3, otherwise, getdate()-1.

I have tried declaring a variable, I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                    ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```

which doesn't work because the column from my table called create_date to be set to the correct dynamic date.  This works if I run it alone without trying to incorporate into a query (gives me the date for Friday) but I can not figure out how to then take that date and apply it to my query.

This is the closest I have been able to get

```
DECLARE @CREATIONDAY DATE 

SET @CREATIONDAY = DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, convert(date,GETDATE()))
                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                    ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()));

SELECT CREATION_DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[workflow_document]
WHERE CREATION_DATE = @CREATIONDAY
GROUP BY CREATION_DATE
```

but still getting an error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ','."

Not sure what could be wrong with the comma, but I am about at the end of my rope with getting this to work.  Anything is appreciated!

Comment: What about public holidays, are they considered business day?

Comment: Im scared to say I need to also filter out holidays because Im not sure how this affects the query / if I will need to build table and join it with my query, since I am trying to use Tableau for data viz some of the things we use in SQL do not translate to Tableau.  Is there an easy way to kick out holidays as well?

Comment: The common way is a calendar table where all the things you ever need are precalculated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is fine.  Your variable definition has `DAY,` in it.  So:

```
SET @CREATIONDAY = DATEADD(DAY,
                           (CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, convert(date,GETDATE()))
                              WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                              WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                              ELSE -1
                            END),
                           GETDATE());
```

Or, just add the logic into the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' AND
       CREATION_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -2, CAST(GETDATE as DATE))
      ) OR
      (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Monday' AND
       CREATION_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -3, CAST(GETDATE as DATE))
      ) OR
      (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' AND
       CREATION_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -2, CAST(GETDATE as DATE))
      ) OR
      (DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) NOT IN ('Sunday', 'Monday') AND
       CREATION_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE as DATE))
      )
```

Comment: Im wanting to try out this solution, but when I incorporate this into my WHERE clause, Im getting the following error: "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'GETDATE'." for all of the CAST(GETDATE as....)  Any ideas there?

EDIT: Got it, just missing the () after getdate!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with day-of-week calculations, it's important to take account of the current [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql) settings. This query will always correctly exclude weekend days, using [@@DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql) to account for any possible setting for the first day of the week.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, date_created) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this was the answer you where looking for please mark it as the best answer